# Java Class Immutable with Thread Safe Collection

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, immutability

Suppose if I have the following class:

```
public final class Person {

   final private String personFirstName;
   final private String personLastName;
   final private ConcurrentMap<Double, String> phoneMessages;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
       phoneMessages = new ConcurrentHashMap<Double, String>();
       this.personFirstName = firstname;
       this.personLastName = lastname;
    }

    public void add(Double key, String item) {
        phoneMessages.put(key, item);
    }

    public String getPersonFirstName() {
        return personFirstName;
    }

    public String getPersonLastName() {
        return personLastName;
    }

}
```

Even though I created a class with a private final thread-safe collection, is my class immutable? My guess is no.

If having a collection in an object isn't proper practice what is the proper practice in Java? How would I go about designing my class that contains a collection?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be proper practice? Not *everything* needs to be immutable.

Comment: @JBNizet - I've been waiting to read those words for the longest time. I was reading about immutable classes, and the impression I got about mutable classes was NO! I began rethinking a lot of my code, and this issue came up, so the way its designed, you'd leave it? You wouldn't change anything?

Comment: I didn't say that either. It's often a good idea to make classes immutable. And sometimes it's not. It all depends on the problem to solve, the nature of the class, and its intended usage. This class could easily be made immutable by passing the phone messages in the constructor, making a copy in the constructor, and removing the `add()` method. If you provide an accessor to the map, then make sure it returns a copy or an unmodifiable view of the map.

Comment: Then that would mean creating the same person object for new messages?

Comment: @Nexusfactor What do you want to know - how to make an immutable class or if how to use collection in a class?

Comment: how to use collection in a class?

Comment: Again. All I know about your code is this class. I don't know anything about what you intend to do with it, the context in which it's used, etc. So it's impossible to recommend one design over another.

Comment: Could you show me in code, how you would make this class immutable? I wanted to design it as one person could have more than 1 phone message

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/25ac763b56f49df6798d

Comment: @JBNizet - Many thanks, just one quick question, let's say if a new phone message comes in and I want to add it to the list, I would add the new message to the Map, and recreate the object?

Comment: You would create another map, and another Person instance using that map. By definition, an immutable object may not be modified after it has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, ***how*** you use your class will determine if making it immutable is appropriate.

That said, this version of your `Person` class is immutable:

```
public final class Person {

   final private  String personFirstName;
   final private  String personLastName;
   final private ConcurrentMap<Double,String> phoneMessages;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
       this.phoneMessages = new ConcurrentHashMap<Double,String> ();
       this.personFirstName = firstname;
       this.personLastName  = lastname;
    }

    private Person(String firstname, String lastname, ConcurrentHashMap<Double,String> phoneMessages) {
       this.personFirstName = firstname;
       this.personLastName  = lastname;
       this.phoneMessages = phoneMessages;
    }

    public Person add(Double Key, String item){
        ConcurrentHashMap<Double, String> newMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(this.phoneMessages);
        newMap.put(Key, item);
        return new Person(this.personFirstName, this.personLastName, newMap);
    }

    public String getPersonFirstName() {
        return personFirstName;
    }

    public String getPersonLastName() {
        return personLastName;
    }

    public Map<Double, String> getPhoneMessages() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.phoneMessages);
    }

}
```

Notice that the `add` method returns a different instance of `Person` so that the current `Person` instance remains unmodified (immutable).

Comment: If I just wanted to return the collection, could I return a readonly type of collection? Rather than get a new Person object with the map. Could I implement a getter that returns a readonly collection is what I'm asking.

Comment: You can use `Collections.unmodifiableMap` for that (see my edited post).  But your biggest concern to retain immutability should be methods like `add` that change the internal state of your object.  To preserve immutability in those cases, you have to create a new `Person` instance and apply the change on that new instance instead of the current one.  This is very similar to how some methods on `String` work (e.g. `replace`).